# Detail view of listview

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

Here is my async task.i want display the detailview of a listview click.there is some error in displaying data in text view.i know we cant access UI inside doInBackground.i dont know how to do in OnpostExecute.help me

```
class Enquiryview extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

     protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EnquiryDetail.this);
        // pDialog.setMessage("Loding...");
         pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
         pDialog.setCancelable(true);
         pDialog.show();
     }
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


           // final String URL_LIST = "http://staging.homeneedsonline.com/ws/ws_address_detail.php?user_id="+ userid1+"";
            final String URL_LIST = "http://staging.homeneedsonline.com/ws/ws_enq_detail.php?ser_enq_id="+ enq_id+"";

               System.out.println(URL_LIST);
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();    

           final JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL_LIST, get, params);



            System.out.println("enq----do in ---"+json);
            try {    
               String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                 System.out.println("enq---------------is"+enq_id);
                int res1 = Integer.parseInt(res);
               if (res1 == 1) {
                  // String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                   //System.out.println(res);

                    JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject("detail");

                     // setListAdapter(mAdapter);

                     // JSONArray json1=new JSONArray("data");

                       //Log.d("Address JSON: ", "> " + albums);

                     // Storing each json item values in variable
                      final String enqid = jsonObject.getString(ENQID);
                       String enqdate = jsonObject.getString(ENQ_DATE);
                       String status = jsonObject.getString(STATUS);
                       String usc = jsonObject.getString(USC);
                       String amount = jsonObject.getString(AMOUNT);

                    String address = jsonObject.getString(ENQ_ADDRESS);
                     String city = jsonObject.getString(CITY);
                    String state = jsonObject.getString(STATE);


                System.out.println(enqid);
                System.out.println(enqdate);

                System.out.println(usc);

                System.out.println(address);

                System.out.println(city);

                System.out.println(state);
               // service.setText();
                amounttext.setText(amount);
                //exname.setText();
                statustext.setText(status);
                addresstext.setText(address);

                citytext.setText(city);

                statetext.setText(state);

                //billno.setText();
                usctext.setText(usc);
                date.setText(enqdate);
                enqidtext.setText(enqid);



               }
               else
               {
                   Log.d("Addressssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss: ", "null");


               }

         } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

            return json;
        }

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(final JSONObject json1) {
            // check for login response
           /// System.out.println("enq----on post ---"+json);

            pDialog.dismiss();
               // Check your log cat for JSON reponse

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Enquiryview extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {


final JSONObject json;
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EnquiryDetail.this);
   // pDialog.setMessage("Loding...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}
   protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
       List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


      // final String URL_LIST = "http://staging.homeneedsonline.com/ws/ws_address_detail.php?user_id="+ userid1+"";
       final String URL_LIST = "http://staging.homeneedsonline.com/ws/ws_enq_detail.php?ser_enq_id="+ enq_id+"";

          System.out.println(URL_LIST);
       JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();    

      json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL_LIST, get, params);

      return null;


   }

   protected void onPostExecute(final JSONObject json1) {
       // check for login response
      /// System.out.println("enq----on post ---"+json);

       System.out.println("enq----do in ---"+json);
       try {    
          String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
            System.out.println("enq---------------is"+enq_id);
           int res1 = Integer.parseInt(res);
          if (res1 == 1) {
             // String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
              //System.out.println(res);

               JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject("detail");

                // setListAdapter(mAdapter);

                // JSONArray json1=new JSONArray("data");

                  //Log.d("Address JSON: ", "> " + albums);

                // Storing each json item values in variable
                 final String enqid = jsonObject.getString(ENQID);
                  String enqdate = jsonObject.getString(ENQ_DATE);
                  String status = jsonObject.getString(STATUS);
                  String usc = jsonObject.getString(USC);
                  String amount = jsonObject.getString(AMOUNT);

               String address = jsonObject.getString(ENQ_ADDRESS);
                String city = jsonObject.getString(CITY);
               String state = jsonObject.getString(STATE);


           System.out.println(enqid);
           System.out.println(enqdate);

           System.out.println(usc);

           System.out.println(address);

           System.out.println(city);

           System.out.println(state);
          // service.setText();
           amounttext.setText(amount);
           //exname.setText();
           statustext.setText(status);
           addresstext.setText(address);

           citytext.setText(city);

           statetext.setText(state);

           //billno.setText();
           usctext.setText(usc);
           date.setText(enqdate);
           enqidtext.setText(enqid);



          }
          else
          {
              Log.d("Addressssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss: ", "null");


          }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

       return ;
   }


       pDialog.dismiss();
          // Check your log cat for JSON reponse

   }
```

Try this

Comment: printed json is null in OnPostexecute.

Comment: its fyn bcz the json  object is global variable

Comment: or you can use  return json;  too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return JsonObject from doInBackground method and whatever json parsing you are doing the doInBackground you need to move it to the onPostExecute() method. 
Let me know if it helps you